# Improved version of UPDATE and INNER JOIN at webscale table (Table with million+ entries)

Tags: sql, database, sql-update, h2

I have `table2` with a few thousand rows, and `table1` with millions of rows (`table2` is a subset of `table1`).

I want to update table1 basis on matching record from `table2` (record-identifier).

Initial snapshot:

`table1`:

```
id  data  moredata
-------------------
1   abc   def
2   ghi   jkl
```

`table2`:

```
id  data  moredata
-------------------
1   abc   defg
```

Desired result:

```
 id  data  moredata
 ------------------
 1   abc   defg
 2   ghi   jkl
```

Now I read that the naive way of achieving this is to use `UPDATE` using `INNER JOIN`. further research on the same revealed that it performs almost m*n comparison while checking the given condition.

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.moredata = table2.moredata 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id;
```

How can I consider entries in table2 only and update table1 basis on that? Please let me know how can I optimize the given query.

Comment: Is it one-time task? Then just do it, performance does not matter (and it likely will perform well, assuming `id` is primary key). There is nothing to optimise, unless you have left something important out.

Comment: Unfortunately. this will be a frequent task. and as far as I know, I have mentioned all the details.

Comment: Yoiu can add `where` clause there: `where table1.moredata <> table2.moredata`, this may decrease [exclusive] locking needs. Further depends on specific SQL engine - I can only talk about Microsoft SQL Server, there such update is usually pretty quick. You should not be afraid of m*n operations, you should measure performance, look at query plans and then decide, do you need any optimisation or not. There was once saying "premature optimization is the root of all evil" :)

Comment: How many rows of table2 do you expect to have a match in table1?

Comment: @Arvo good point. What I am afraid of is, this updation needs to be in a single transaction and should not take down db while performing the operation. thus I was looking for not reaching up to m*n comparisons.

Comment: @TheImpaler range is 10-100k rows that should be updated. being said that 100k is the extreme case but we have few ids with such entries.

Comment: BTW, if sql engine decides to use merge operation on sorted sets (primary keys are likely sorted), then there will be about m+n comparisons internally, not m*n - but it takes more memory and disk reads this way. All this depends on optimizer estimations and table statistics. Re "needs single transaction" - this is such minor detail, which for example prohibits me to suggest "update your data in short batches" or similar.

Comment: I would create two indexes: `table1 (id, moredata)` and `table2 (id, moredata)`. And I would also add the extra `WHERE` predicate as indicated by @Arvo.

Comment: You seem to be concerned about how long this will take.  Have you tried the `INNER JOIN` solution on a dev server?  How long did it actually take?  You say a few thousand rows in table2 and millions of rows in table1.  How many millions?  4?  400?  Either way, it doesn't seem really that big to me if the database is designed and optimized (indexing, perhaps) and your query is optimized (for example, properly taking advantage of database partitioning, etc.).  After you try it out in Dev, post the actual results and the desired results.

Comment: Also, provide information about indexes and partitions.

Comment: _the naive way of achieving this is to use UPDATE using INNER JOIN_ It's not a naive way, it's a standard and acceptable way of describing what you want to do in SQL. The actual mechanics of how it is implemented are decided by your database platform, existing indexes, etc. As already mentioned it might use a merge join (fast) or not. As already mentioned it's not a given that it requires m*n

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using a SQL database system that supports it (like PostgreSQL, SQL Server). Then, I guess you can use an `UPDATE FROM` statement to optimize this. In your case, probably something like:

```
UPDATE table1
SET moredata = table2.moredata
FROM table2
WHERE table1.id = table2.id;
```

This should be more efficient than using an `INNER JOIN` because the `WHERE` clause effectively narrows down the rows that need to be examined to only those where `table1.id` exists in `table2`.

If you are using MySQL, I belive the syntax is a bit different, but you can still use a `JOIN` to achieve the same effect:

```
UPDATE table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
SET table1.moredata = table2.moredata;
```

These queries will only update rows in `table1` where the `id` exists in `table2`.

It's also worth noting that the efficiency of these queries can depend a lot on how your database is indexed.

Comment: _This should be more efficient...._ I'm sorry, this is a fallacy. The query planner decides how and what order to filter and join. Nowadays almost all database do exactly the same thing when using either `INNER JOIN` or `WHERE` to define the join